# Ruby Problems Displaying Variables From New View, but Not Edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

In my app I have a quiz in a partial because I need the same (lengthy) quiz for my `new` and for my `edit` view.  In the header of the `application.html.erb` and on my `users#show` page I display the results from this quiz, once it is taken, using an if/else statement.  For some reason, after a user takes the quiz in the `new` view it is registering that the quiz has been completed (you can tell by the if/else statement) but not displaying the variables.  However, using the `edit` view (that calls the same partial `_quiz.html.erb`) the variables display perfectly.

My `new` view calls the partial like this:

```
<%= render partial: "quiz", locals: { url: swing_books_path, method: :post } %>
```

While my `edit` view calls it like this:

```
<%= render partial: "quiz", locals: { url: edit_swing_book_path(@swing_book), method: :put } %>
```

The partial looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @swing_book do |f| %>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <h1 class="text-center">
    <%= f.text_field :swing01, class: 'form-control input-1' %>
    <%= f.text_field :swing02, class: 'form-control input-1' %>
    <%= f.text_field :swing03, class: 'form-control input-1' %>
    -
    <%= f.text_field :swing04, class: 'form-control input-1' %>
    <%= f.text_field :swing05, class: 'form-control input-1' %>
    <%= f.text_field :swing06, class: 'form-control input-1' %>
    -
    <%= f.text_field :swing07, class: 'form-control input-1' %>
    <%= f.text_field :swing08, class: 'form-control input-1' %>
    <%= f.text_field :swing09, class: 'form-control input-1' %>
    <%= f.text_field :swing10, class: 'form-control input-1' %>
   </h1>

   <div class="form-group text-center">
      <%= f.submit "Submit Swing Code", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
   </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

However, I use these exact same details (with just the variable names changed) on another quiz that is not having the same issue.  (I have three other similar quizzes all of which display perfectly from both `new` and `edit` views.)

My model looks like this:

```
class SwingBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_swing_code

  def set_swing_code
    self.swing_code = "#{self.swing01}#{self.swing02}#{self.swing03}-#{self.swing04}#{self.swing05}#{self.swing06}-#{self.swing07}#{self.swing08}#{self.swing09}#{self.swing10}"
  end

  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class SwingBooksController < ApplicationController
before_action :require_sign_in

def show
  @swing_book = SwingBook.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @swing_book = current_user.build_swing_book
end

def create
  @swing_book = SwingBook.new

  @swing_book.swing_code = params[:swing_book][:swing01]
  @swing_book.swing_code = params[:swing_book][:swing02]
  @swing_book.swing_code = params[:swing_book][:swing03]
  @swing_book.swing_code = params[:swing_book][:swing04]
  @swing_book.swing_code = params[:swing_book][:swing05]
  @swing_book.swing_code = params[:swing_book][:swing06]
  @swing_book.swing_code = params[:swing_book][:swing07]
  @swing_book.swing_code = params[:swing_book][:swing08]
  @swing_book.swing_code = params[:swing_book][:swing09]
  @swing_book.swing_code = params[:swing_book][:swing10]
  @swing_book.swing_code = params[:swing_book][:swing_code]

  @swing_book.user = current_user

  if @swing_book.save
    flash[:notice] = "Your swing code was saved successfully."
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Sorry, your results failed to save."
    redirect_to welcome_index_path
  end
end

def edit
  @swing_book = SwingBook.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @swing_book = SwingBook.find(params[:id])

  @swing_book.assign_attributes(swing_book_params)

  if @swing_book.save
    flash[:notice] = "Results were updated successfully."
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error saving your results. Please try again."
    redirect_to welcome_index_path
  end
end

private
def swing_book_params
  params.require(:swing_book).permit(:swing01, :swing02, :swing03, :swing04, :swing05, :swing06, :swing07, :swing08, :swing09, :swing10, :swing_code)
end
end
```

Finally, here's the logic I'm using to display these variables in the `application.html.erb` file:

```
<% if current_user.swing_book != nil %>
  <p>ID Code:
    <%= current_user.swing_book.swing01 %>
    <%= current_user.swing_book.swing02 %>
    <%= current_user.swing_book.swing03 %>
    -
    <%= current_user.swing_book.swing04 %>
    <%= current_user.swing_book.swing05 %>
    <%= current_user.swing_book.swing06 %>
    -
    <%= current_user.swing_book.swing07 %>
    <%= current_user.swing_book.swing08 %>
    <%= current_user.swing_book.swing09 %>
    <%= current_user.swing_book.swing10 %></p>
<% end %>
```

And on the `user#show` page:

```
<% if @user.swing_book == nil %>
  <h3>ID Code: ???-???-????<%= %></h3>
  <p><%= link_to "Get Your ID Code Now!", new_swing_book_path %></p>
<% else %>
  <h3>ID Code:
    <%= @user.swing_book.swing01 %>
    <%= @user.swing_book.swing02 %>
    <%= @user.swing_book.swing03 %>
    -
    <%= @user.swing_book.swing04 %>
    <%= @user.swing_book.swing05 %>
    <%= @user.swing_book.swing06 %>
    -
    <%= @user.swing_book.swing07 %>
    <%= @user.swing_book.swing08 %>
    <%= @user.swing_book.swing09 %>
    <%= @user.swing_book.swing10 %></h3>
  <p><%= link_to "Update Your Code", edit_swing_book_path(@user.swing_book) %></p>
 <% end %>
```

I originally tried displaying just the `swing_code` variable (as established in the `method`, but it was displaying a single integer so I switched to the code seen above.  Ideally, I would like to display it as just the `swing_code` variable, but the (somewhat repetitive) workaround I'm currently using works fine-ish if I could only get the `new`/`edit` display issue worked out.

Any ideas as to what could be going wrong?  I can't find any differences between this and the other quizzes that could be causing a problem!

Comment: have you tried using a debugger like the `byebug` gem? you can place a breakpoint in your view with `<% byebug %>` and then inspect the values in your terminal.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Ruby and have heard of the `byebug` gem but have no idea how to use it...

Comment: it will work wonders in helping you debug problems. How it works is simple - you require the gem, and write `byebug` anywhere in your code. Then when that area of the code gets run, the program pauses. You can manually inspect all the variables at that point in time. Then you can press `next` to move to the next line or `continue` to stop the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `create` method, you have a block of code that explicitly sets the `@swing_book` values.  This code is setting all of the values from the form into just the `swing_code` member.  Since the last assignment is also from the `swing_code` param to the `swing_code` member, it's hiding the mistake.  Here's the code with the correct member fields assigned:

```
@swing_book.swing01 = params[:swing_book][:swing01]
@swing_book.swing02 = params[:swing_book][:swing02]
@swing_book.swing03 = params[:swing_book][:swing03]
@swing_book.swing04 = params[:swing_book][:swing04]
@swing_book.swing05 = params[:swing_book][:swing05]
@swing_book.swing06 = params[:swing_book][:swing06]
@swing_book.swing07 = params[:swing_book][:swing07]
@swing_book.swing08 = params[:swing_book][:swing08]
@swing_book.swing09 = params[:swing_book][:swing09]
@swing_book.swing10 = params[:swing_book][:swing10]
@swing_book.swing_code = params[:swing_book][:swing_code]
```

Now, while that will fix the immediate problem, you probably just want to use the same approach as the `update` method.  Try this for your `create` method, instead:

```
def create
  @swing_book = SwingBook.new

  @swing_book.assign_attributes(swing_book_params)
  @swing_book.user = current_user

  if @swing_book.save
    flash[:notice] = "Your swing code was saved successfully."
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Sorry, your results failed to save."
    redirect_to welcome_index_path
  end
end
```

However, you have an opportunity to minimize the overall code to help eliminate errors like this.  Consider something like this for your controller code:

```
class SwingBooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_sign_in

  def show
    @swing_book = SwingBook.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @swing_book = current_user.build_swing_book
  end

  def edit
    @swing_book = SwingBook.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @swing_book = SwingBook.new
    apply_form_values
  end

  def update
    @swing_book = SwingBook.find(params[:id])
    apply_form_values
  end

private
  def apply_form_values
    @swing_book.assign_attributes(swing_book_params)

    if @swing_book.save
      flash[:notice] = "Results were updated successfully."
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error saving your results. Please try again."
      redirect_to welcome_index_path
    end
  end

  def swing_book_params
    params.require(:swing_book).permit(:swing01, :swing02, :swing03, :swing04, :swing05, :swing06, :swing07, :swing08, :swing09, :swing10, :swing_code)
  end
end
```

You can use techniques like this to make it easier to write your initial code, and make it far easier to maintain.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you!